# Circular reference with ManyToMany relationship and automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design, automapper

Given the following Domain Entities:

```
public class Person {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<PersonClub> Clubs { get; set; }

    public Person() {
        this.Clubs = new HashSet<PersonClub>();
    }
}

public class Club {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<PersonClub> Members { get; set; }

    public Club() {
        this.Persons = new HashSet<PersonClub>();
    }
}

public class PersonClub {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
}
```

and DTO's:

```
public class PersonDTO {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ISet<ClubDTO> Clubs { get; set; }

    public PersonDTO() {
        this.Clubs = new HashSet<ClubDTO>();
    }
}

public class ClubDTO {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ISet<PersonDTO> Members { get; set; }

    public ClubDTO() {
        this.Members = new HashSet<PersonDTO>();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to map these Domain Entities to their DTO's? The problem is that PersonDTO needs a collection of ClubDTO, not just Club, and vice versa for ClubDTO needing a collection of PersonDTO and not just Person.

This design causes an infinite loop when trying to map PersonClub -> PersonDTO and PersonClub -> ClubDTO:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Club, ClubDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonClub, ClubDTO>()
    .ConvertUsing(x => Mapper.Map<Club, ClubDTO>(x.Club));
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonClub, PersonDTO>()
    .ConvertUsing(x => Mapper.Map<Person, PersonDTO>(x.Person));
```

I understand why this is happening, but am curious to how others handle this situation.

In this situation when calling `Mapper.Map<Person, PersonDTO>(personEntity)`, it isn't necessary to load all members of all clubs that a person is a part of (The relationship doesn't need to go that deep ever). Same is true for `Mapper.Map<Club, ClubDTO>(clubEntity)`.

Is this a design flaw? Would it be better to not have a PersonClub domain entity and just have `public virtual ISet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }` as the ManyToMany relationship? Although I believe this would still cause the circular reference.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you have a PersonClubDto? That would make your life quite a bit easier.

Comment: If I did create a PersonClubDTO, I'd still have to convert each Person -> PersonDTO and Club -> ClubDTO member, which would still cause a circular reference.